# What are some differences between applications and applets?

Tags: java, applet

Can someone tell me some differences between applications and applets?

Comment: applets are the cuter version of applications! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applets have the following [methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/appletMethods.html):

init(), start(),stop(),destroy()

An applet can live inside the browser and outside the browser with the [draggable feature](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/draggableApplet.html).
An application is executed outside the browser.

Comment: Good description, but note that the term 'applet' originally meant basically a small application, and this meaning was effectively hi-hacked by embedded Java based applets.  Some Java applets are not small (comprising 10-20 Meg of download) while there are many little 'settings applets' and the like on *nix systems that are neither written in Java nor embedded in a browser.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of *all* the differences, but the major one is that Applets are executed in a sandbox environment, where they are restricted by strict policies. For instance, you cannot access the local file system unless your applet is [signed](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html)

Applets are usually not recommended in favor of Web applications using Javascript and Ajax calls.

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong in two respects. 1) Applets are only sandboxed by default - but can have their privileges raised by being signed by the programmer and accepted by the user (when prompted). 2) In a 1.6.0_10+ JRE (the 'Plug-In 2 architecture') embedded applets can hook into the JNLP API services which allow even sand-boxed apps. to gain access to the local file system (again with user approval).  You can see a demo. of the former at http://pscode.org/test/docload/ & the latter at http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, isn't this what I said? "unless your applet is signed" you are restricted by security policies by the virtual machine. There's nothing wrong with that paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the differences:

1. Application must have main() method, Applet doesn't contain main().
2. Applets can not interact with Our Local Machine.
3. Applets runs inside a browser which have JVM embedded or in AppletViewer.