# What is the main difference in packaging an applet vs. an application (for deployment) in Eclipse?

Tags: java

Couldn't find a thread that explained the difference between both.

What is the difference?

Thank you to all that helps!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Well, I don't know how else to explain it... the question seems pretty straight forward. Would you explain what you don't understand?

Comment: Why am I getting down voted? It's just a general question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean under `packaging` and how Eclipse relates to deployment.

Comment: Applications are contained in a .jar file along with all relevant files, and are opened as standalone processes on a computer. Applets are for embedding into web pages. By the way, I'd really love if people on this site could just give an answer based on their interpretation, it's always good to learn *something*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some differences between applications and applets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481394/what-are-some-differences-between-applications-and-applets)

Answer (score 2):

[Applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) is typically used to be started from within a browser, means it is embedded in a website, like a Flash plugin or video.

An application (in the way I think you mean) is typically a standalone software, which can be started and executed alone, without any extra piece of software beside the JVM.

Another typically difference is, that an application is mostly stored on your local machine and an applet loaded at start time from a remote host.

Because of this Eclipse needs to package (and start) them in a different way.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian! At least someone understood me!

Comment: How your answer addresses `packaging`? It seems that you answer for "difference between applet and application" which can be easily googled.

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov Yep thanks, just realized this on my own. But from an Eclipse point of view I don't think it matters, as Eclipse does all the hard work for you ;) Truly, you are right, technically it's quity more completed.

Answer (score 0):

When you run java in eclipse, it more like eclipse compile your code into java native class, then run it with following command:
java -options yourcode.class
and you can find there has another java process in windows task manager, you can check the java launch options in eclipse preference.
Run code in applet, windows will know it's need to be opened by java, like run command line with command: java yourcode.class
without any options.